# Android Firebase createUser() is not Working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a user in the Firebase console using email and password but it doesn't work showing an error.
Actually we can add users in the console by going to the dashboard and clicking on `add user` but I want to automate this process.

Here's the full code:

```
    import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.client.AuthData;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

import java.util.Map;

public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private SignInButton mSignInButton;
    private Button but;
    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    String user_id="",pass="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
        email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.emails);


        password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwords);

        but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.create);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(getBaseContext());

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                user_id= email.getText().toString();
                pass= password.getText().toString();
               Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://final-6b828.firebaseio.com/auth");
                ref.createUser(user_id, pass, new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {
                        System.out.println("Successfully created user account with uid: " + result.get("uid"));
                        String a=  result.get("uid").toString();
                        Log.i("Success",user_id);
                        Log.i("Success",pass);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pass",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                        // there was an error
                        System.out.println("Failed to create user account : ");
                        Log.i("Failed","a");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });


            }
        });


        mSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);


        mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        // Initialize FirebaseAuth
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    private void handleFirebaseAuthResult(AuthResult authResult) {
        if (authResult != null) {

            FirebaseUser user = authResult.getUser();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome " + user.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();

                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {

                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
                Log.e(TAG, "Google Sign In Successfull.");
            } else {

                Log.e(TAG, "Google Sign In failed.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGooogle:" + acct.getId());
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(5000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
}
```

The code used to create an user is :

```
but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            user_id= email.getText().toString();
            pass= password.getText().toString();
           Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://final-6b828.firebaseio.com/auth");
            ref.createUser(user_id, pass, new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {
                    System.out.println("Successfully created user account with uid: " + result.get("uid"));
                    String a=  result.get("uid").toString();
                    Log.i("Success",user_id);
                    Log.i("Success",pass);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pass",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    // there was an error
                    System.out.println("Failed to create user account : ");
                    Log.i("Failed","a");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });


        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Sachin, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please edit your question with the error you get creating a user?
You have posted a lot of code here! Can you please reduce it? :)

Comment: hi Devid,thanks for responding.now i got the answer.the code i used to create a user was wrong.i got the correct code from. [link]https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/EmailPasswordActivity.java#L69-L69.......thanks.

Comment: @SachinVarma If you solved your own question please post an answer with the code(instead of adding it to the question) and accept it so the question will not remain unsolved.

Comment: @Luksprog,thanks for the comment,it is edited now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code to create a user is..

```
but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            user_id= email.getText().toString();
           pass= password.getText().toString();
            createAccount(user_id,pass);
 }
    });

 private void createAccount(String email, String password) {
    Log.d(TAG, "createAccount:" + email);
    if (!validateForm()) {
        return;
    }

   // showProgressDialog();

    // [START create_user_with_email]
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    //hideProgressDialog();
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
    // [END create_user_with_email]
}
private boolean validateForm() {
    boolean valid = true;

    String emails = email.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(emails)) {
       email.setError("Required.");
        valid = false;
    } else {
       email.setError(null);
    }

    String passwords = password.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(passwords)) {
        password.setError("Required.");
        valid = false;
    } else {
       password.setError(null);
    }

    return valid;
}
```