# Task.isSuccessful() is false and unable to add any user kotlin - firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm seeing the task.isSuccessfull false when I do debug and I can't create a record. I did all the work. I also did the email and password authorization from the firebase website. However, I cannot create a record because it is false. As I said, I did all the steps to be given on the website.
In the detail of the error he writes:
A network error has occurred (such as timeout, interrupted connection, or unreachable host).

```
    private fun createNewAccount() {
    email = emailEdt?.text.toString()
    password = passwordEdt?.text.toString()
    confirmPassword = confirmPasswordEdt?.text.toString()

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(confirmPassword)) {
        mProgressBar!!.setMessage("Hesabınız Oluşturuluyor")
        mProgressBar!!.show()

        mAuth!!.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email!!, password!!)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                mProgressBar!!.hide()

                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "CreateAccount: success")

                    val userId = mAuth!!.currentUser!!.uid

                    verifyEmail();
                    val currentUserDb = mDatabaseReference!!.child(userId)
                    currentUserDb.child("email").setValue(email)
                    updateUserInfo()
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "CreateAccount: failure")
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Kayıt oluşturulamadı.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }
            }


    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Lütfen tüm alanları doldurunuz.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `task.getException()` to get a more detailed view of what went wrong?

Comment: yes i tried and i wrote above.
I get such an error
A network error has occurred (such as timeout, interrupted connection, or unreachable host).

Comment: Sounds like a network problem.  Make sure the device has a working network connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Firebase createUser() is not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38157560/android-firebase-createuser-is-not-working)

Comment: solve the problem related to the device
thanks